# Save records from a tcxgrid into an xml file - Delphi XE2

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe2, tcxgrid

I would like to know the simplest way to get what you see in a tcxgrid and at the click of a button, will then save the records into an xml file.

Comment: What part do you know and what don't you know? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for TcxGrid? From simple google searches there seems to be an aptly named function `ExportGridToXML`. Have you tried that? is it not working?

Comment: so far I have a form with the tcxgrid on it and a button, i have a data module which is talking to a database with tadqueries which are looking at tables in the database. The tcxgrid is displaying the correct data when running the program. Thats exactly where i am up to, if this helps. any further help would be much appreciated.

Comment: not heard of the ExportGridToXML function, il check it out thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only slight problem with using the ExportGridToXML procedure is that it's fairly well hidden - you need to add the cxGridExportLink unit to your uses list.

```
uses
  cxGridExportLink;

procedure TForm1.SaveToXML1;
var
  FileName : String;
begin
  FileName := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(GetEnvironmentVariable('Temp'));
  FileName := FileName + 'Grid.XML';
  ExportGridToXML(FileName, cxGrid1);
end;
```

That will save the XML file to \users[your name]\appdata\local\Temp.  Note that it will include only the dataset fields that have columns in the grid, which may be what you want, or not, depending.

The procedure below shows another way of saving a dataset to XML that bypasses the grid, and saves the data values for all of the dataset's fields, regardless of whether they have columns in a cxGrid.  It works by copying the dataset's data to a temporary TClientDataSet via a TDataSetProvider and then using the TClientDataSet's built-in facility to save its data to XML.  It will respect any filter that the dataset passed to it might have in place.

```
procedure TForm1.SaveToXML2(DataSet : TDataSet);
var
  FileName : String;
  DSP : TDataSetProvider;
  CDS : TClientDataSet;
begin
  FileName := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(GetEnvironmentVariable('Temp'));
  FileName := FileName + 'Grid2.XML';

  DSP := TDataSetProvider.Create(Self);
  CDS := TClientDataSet.Create(Self);

  try
    DSP.DataSet := DataSet;
    DSP.Name := 'TempProvider';
    CDS.ProviderName := DSP.Name;
    DataSet.DisableControls;  // otherwise you will see the source dataset scrolling 
    // if it's shown in a grid
    CDS.Open;
    CDS.SaveToFile(FileName, dfXML);
  finally
    DataSet.EnableControls;
    CDS.Free;
    DSP.Free;
  end;
end;
```